# Error when setting up .flaskenv file for flask application with python-dotenv

Tags: python, windows, flask

I installed `python-dotenv` to my virtual environment and I created a `.flaskenv` file with the contents as:

```
FLASK_APP=hello_world.py
```

to manually avoid `set FLASK_APP=hello_world.py` 
everytime when I run my application.

But I don't know why when I do `flask run`,

It shows an error `"Error: Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module was not found in the current directory."`.

Could somebody help me on how to fix this using `.flaskenv` ? I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Your app.py needs to be in the same directory where .flaskenv is located.